# Multiple labels from same variable using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

How can I have a set of labels for a location, where the variables are within a single column?

What I am hoping for is to have placement of 'concentration' followed by depth at each location shown on label.

Example of my data:

Loc_ID (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2...)   Depth_m (0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0)   Conc. (1, 0.2, <LOR, 1 ,no data, 0.2) etc...

I have tried CASE and coalesce. However, in an instance where there is no data, the label shows an empty line, which is not required.

I am using QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I did not understand you properly; I thought you might want an expression like:

```
CASE 
WHEN "Conc" != 'no data'
THEN 'Loc_ID: '  + to_string("Loc_ID")  + '\n' + 
     'Depth_m: ' + to_string("Depth_m") + '\n' + 'Conc: '    + to_string("Conc")
ELSE 'Loc_ID: '  + to_string("Loc_ID")  + '\n' + 'Depth_m: ' + to_string("Depth_m")
END
```

in the Field Calculator -

[image]

Which will produce a new field for the label:

[image]

---

**[UPDATE]**

To make a "grouped" label at each 'Loc_ID', you can use `concatenate()` function.

Using the previously made `"Label"` field, the expression would be:

```
concatenate("Label" , group_by:= "Loc_ID", concatenator:= '\n', order_by:= 'Depth_m')
```

[image]

Given this is what you are up to, the expression for `"Label"` field should be simplified as below:

```
CASE WHEN  "Conc" != 'no data'
THEN 'Depth_m: ' + to_string("Depth_m") + ' , ' + 'Conc: ' + to_string("Conc")
ELSE 'Depth_m: ' + to_string("Depth_m")
END
```

The final attribute table becomes:

[image]

Please use the `"oneLabel"' field to add the label.

Comment: Just a clarification. is there a condition where i could have the 'various' depths and conc under a single 'label'? or is that more a edit option in QGIS for labeling a point. cheers!

Comment: @AlanBull Yes, it is called `aggregate` operation. Please see the updated answer. If it is not answering your comment, please let me know.